# Ruby On Rails CMS Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, rubygems

I want to create a framework for rails application. It will be a rails application but packed into gem (like a Radiant CMS).

It must work like this:

```
gem install cmsframework
```

and then:

```
cmsframework the_app
```

After that we have a skeleton framework for a rails app, without any controllers, etc. All controllers are loaded from cmsframework gem.

If I want to rewrite some files (for example public/styles.css), I must simply create it in my app (the_app).

If I want new functions in my app I can create a plugin. But the main functionalities must be loaded from cmsframework gem.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start here: http://guides.rails.info/plugins.html. Pay close attention to the parts about adding custom generators and packaging as a gem. This may help as well: http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this framework it is very good [CamaleonCMS](http://camaleon.tuzitio.com)